# React native render more dimensional array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, array.prototype.map

I would like to map a more dimensional array that looks like this:

```
const array = [
  {
      name: "Anna",
      items: ["Bread", "Cake", "Wine"]
  },
  {
      name: "John",
      items: ["Cucumber", "Pizza", "Jam"]
  }
]
```

I've tried this:

```
class Example extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {
                array.map((data) => { 
                  return(
                  <Text>{data.name}</Text>
                    {
                     data.items.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <Text>{item}</Text>
                        );
                    }
                  );
                  }
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I have also tried to put this into a function that I'm rendering but neither is working for me
can you help ?

Comment: You can only return a single element. Have you tried enclosing the `<Text>...` in a `<View>`?

Comment: when you are using .map then always use index as second parameter.

try to use this  - 
array.map((data,index) => { 
                  return(
                  <Text>{data.name}</Text>
                    {
                     data.items.map((item,index) => {
                        return (
                            <Text>{item}</Text>
                        );
                    }
                  );
                  }

Comment: Also never forget to add keys when rendering jsx elements in loop. Keep unique id for every object in your data and add that as a key

Comment: @ArifRathod Why should they always specify `index` if they aren't using it in the callback?

Comment: @ArifRathod How does index solves the issue? index doesn't matter here

Comment: my code editor says that it detects the second map method as a unreachable code

Comment: Add condition like {data.items && data.items.map((item) => {

Comment: @Think-Twice "index" is for key parameter

Comment: @ArifRathod index is not recommended to use as key

Comment: there is no other unique values in his array. so i suggested to use index for key params. other values may be duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this one can help you. Also you should use key otherwise you got warn during rendering.

```
class Example extends Component {
      _renderYYY(item) {
        console.log(item);
        return item.map((data) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <Text>{data}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        });
      }
      _renderXXX(array) {
        return array.map((data) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <Text key={data.name}>{data.name}</Text>
              {
                this._renderYYY(data.items)
              }
            </View>
          );
        });
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            {
              this._renderXXX(array)
            }
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A limitation of JSX is that a JSX object must always have one single root.

That is,

```
return (
  <Text>One</Text>
  <Text>Two</Text>
);
```

is not valid.

You should wrap the return value of the outer map (including the outer `<Text>` and the inner result of `.map()`) with a root element (probably `<View>`).

**Additionally**, you should always use the `key={}` prop, *and* give it a a globally unique value when rendering an array into JSX.

---

All in all, I'd have something like this:

```
class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {
          array.map((data) => (
            <View key={data.name}>
              <Text>{data.name}</Text>
              {
                data.items.map((item) => (
                  <Text key={data.name + item}>{item}</Text>
                ))
              }
            </View>
          ))
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm assuming that there cannot be duplicate names, and that there cannot be duplicate items inside of a single named object.

Comment: are you sure that you don't have to return something in both map methods ?

Comment: @PaulK I've omitted the curly brackets, this shorter form of arrow functions is `(params) => expression`, and `expression` is returned implicitly from the function, as though I've written `(params) => { return expression; }`. Since a JSX element is a valid expression (it translated directly to a single `React.createElement()` call), it's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here this might help.

```
class Example extends Component {
  renderData = (array) => (
    array.map((data, index) => ([
      <Text key={index}>{data.name}</Text>,
      this.renderItems(data.items)
    ])
  ))

  renderItems = (items) => (
    items.map((item, index) => (
      <Text key={`${item}${index}`}>{item}</Text>
    )
  ))

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          {this.renderData(array)}
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```